# How can I stop HSQL from being used?

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbc, hsqldb, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to use a **basic mysql jdbc** connection but I'm getting HSQLDB errors.

None of the configurations I have indicate that I want to use HSQL.

**Error**:

> org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: <(mytable)>

- This table exists
- I'm using the same query and user/password in mySQL Workbench

How can I avoid using hsql and stick to mysql

**Connection Info**:

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://<HOST>/<SCHEMA>?autoReconnect=true
db.user=<USER>
db.pwd=<PW>
server.port=8000
```

**applicationContext.xml**:

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.pwd}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="5"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
  </bean>
```

**DAO Constructor**:

```
@Repository("myDAO")
public class myDAO implements DAOInterface{

    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

    @Autowired
    public myDAO (DataSource ds) {
        this.dataSource = ds;
        this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
```

**Query:**

```
final String sql = "<QUERY>";
List<DataObj> allData = jdbcTemplateObject.query(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
    @Override
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, param1);
        ps.setString(2,param2);
        ps.setInt(3, param3);
        ps.setString(4,param4);
        ps.setString(5,param5);
        return ps;
    }
}, new DataMapper());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring like to auto-configure datasources.

I needed to set auto-configuration to ignore a number of classes in the application.properties file:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot, but check your `pom.xml` and remove the `hsqldb` dependency if it is there.

Or try to use it only with `test` scope.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This was definitely the first step. I also needed to set autoconfiguration to ignore a number of classes in the application.properties file: `spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration`